# AWS DyanmoDB "failed to load" Status in Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, devops

I've been pulling my hair over this one, and I'm unable to find any answers online regarding the **Status** column in the Dynamo Console.

When we create a Dynamo table using CloudFormation, for some reason when the creation is completed and we open the Console, the **Status** column shows `Failed to load`. At this point the table won't accept any items, it basically won't work.

I tried to delete the CloudFormation Stack and re-create it, but it keeps failing.

I can't think of any other information that may help explain the problem, let me know if anything more is required.

Here is the section defining the Dynamo table in the template:

```
DynamoTable:
  Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
  Properties:
    AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: event_id
        AttributeType: S
    KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: event_id
        KeyType: HASH
    ProvisionedThroughput:
      ReadCapacityUnits: 16
      WriteCapacityUnits: 16
```

This is a screenshot of the **Status** column in the console:

[image: Dynamo Status]

Comment: Might we get the relevant part of the CloudFormation template and any data file / commands used to populate the table please.

Comment: Thanks @DavidJEddy, I updated the post.

Comment: After tinkering around with it a little more, it feels like there is some sort of maximum number of statuses it can load. I haven't confirmed this finding, but here is an example with 10 Dynamo tables 3 of them show **Active** and the rest are **Failed to load**, when I delete one table it seems to be shifting the Active to still have 3 **Active** and the rest **Failed to load**. These numbers are arbitrary, but will post an update soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tinkering with this some more, the fact that this column says **Failed to load** doesn't affect the actual table. That status only reflects loading the status in the list of all Dynamo tables.